# kafka connect logs mounted on localhost from docker

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, log4j, apache-kafka-connect

I have kafka connect running on a docker container which is generating the logs onto a file in /tmp directory. The logs generated in /tmp/kafka-connect.logs on docker should be mounted to local /tmp2/kafka-connect.logs directory. It runs absolutely fine when I mount on /tmp directory - `docker run -p 8083:8083 -v /tmp/:/tmp/ -i jdbc` but fails for `/tmp2` directory - `docker run -p 8083:8083 -v /tmp2/:/tmp/ -i jdbc`. Permissions for /tmp2 directory is `777` privileges and am running as root user.

`connect-log4j.properties`

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger = INFO, FILE, stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d\t%p\t%m\t(%c:%L)%n

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=/tmp/kafka-connect.logs
# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
# use a more detailed message pattern
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d\t%p\t%m\t(%c:%L)%n

log4j.logger.org.apache.zookeeper=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.I0Itec.zkclient=ERROR
```

`Dcockerfile`

```
FROM confluent/platform

MAINTAINER contact@confluent.io
USER root

COPY Test.jar /usr/local/bin/
COPY kafka-connect-docker.sh /usr/local/bin/
COPY connect-distributed.properties /usr/local/bin/
COPY connect-log4j.properties /etc/kafka/

RUN ["apt-get", "update"]
RUN ["apt-get", "install", "-yq", "curl"]
RUN ["chown", "-R", "confluent:confluent", "/usr/local/bin/kafka-connect-docker.sh", "/usr/local/bin/connect-distributed.properties",  "/usr/local/bin/Test.jar"]
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/usr/local/bin/kafka-connect-docker.sh", "/usr/local/bin/connect-distributed.properties", "/usr/local/bin/Test.jar"]
VOLUME [ "/tmp" ]

EXPOSE 8083


CMD [ "/usr/local/bin/kafka-connect-docker.sh" ]
```

`command to run docker image (container)`

```
docker run -p 8083:8083 -v /tmp2/:/tmp/ -i jdbc
```

**Error seen**

```
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/kafka-connect.logs (Permission denied)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:133)
        at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:294)
        at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:165)
        at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:307)
        at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:172)
        at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:104)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:842)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:768)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configureRootCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:648)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:514)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:580)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:526)
        at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:127)
        at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.<init>(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:66)
        at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<init>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:72)
        at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:45)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:150)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:124)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:412)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:357)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:383)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.<clinit>(ConnectDistributed.java:52
```

Comment: why don't you use `/var/log/kafka` inside container and mount to that directory?

Comment: I used `/var/log/kafka` but still same issue. Command - `docker run -p 8083:8083 -v /tmp2:/var/log/kafka -i jdbc`. Any suggestions

Comment: what is default user inside the Dockerfile? Is it root or some other user?

Comment: I am running as root user. `USER root` was not added in Dockerfile, I added it now and its still the same issue